# How to upload amazon s3 using curl using a presigned token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

I am developing an API for the mobile platforms to upload documents.
The process consists of 3 steps:

1. call the API to receive a presigned token set.
2. upload to s3 with that token set.
3. create the document entity with the API using the returned key from step 2.

I have problems with step 2.
Below is the curl command:

```
curl -F "key=<key>/${filename}" 
-F "AWSAccessKeyId=<...>" 
-F "success_action_status=201" 
-F "Policy=<...>" 
-F "Signature=<...>" 
-F "file=@/Users/boti/Desktop/BotondsPhoto.png" https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com
```

The curl command uploads the file and returns an xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostResponse>
  <Location>https://<...>.s3.amazonaws.com/3%2Fe055ff06-9938-4f5c-b5c4-7b6a6df34a6f%2F</Location>
  <Bucket>...</Bucket>
  <Key>3/e055ff06-9938-4f5c-b5c4-7b6a6df34a6f/</Key>
  <ETag>"cccc1defcab53079456f245b8a1e1d2d"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

The problem is with the returned key. The last part ${filename} after the slash should have been substituted with the file name. It should be something like:

```
<Key><key>/Toptal Photo.png</Key>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that the $ sign in the curl command need to be escaped:

```
curl -F "key=<key>/\${filename}" \
-F "AWSAccessKeyId=<...>" \
-F "success_action_status=201" \
-F "Policy=<...>" \
-F "Signature=<...>" \
-F "file=@/Users/boti/Desktop/BotondsPhoto.png" https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com
```